# RESTful API GET method parameters

Tags: api, rest

We are creating a RESTful API (PHP on apache server) which will communicate with an Android application. Im new for this so excuse me if my question is dumb.
I want to ask for data from the api so I need to use GET method in the request taking into account the semantics. I have to send some additional data to specify what data am I requesting. In GET requests, I cannot send form data fields so how should I attach the data?

### Using POST (but this is not semantic)

> request header: POST `http://example.com/api/v1/serials`
>
> request data: date_from=2013.01.01&date_to=2014.01.01&userid=112&is_in=0&starts_with=afx00

### using GET and adding url params (I don't know if is this a good practice in a REST API)

> request header: GET `http://example.com/api/v1/serials?date_from=2013.01.01&date_to=2014.01.01&userid=112&is_in=0&starts_with=afx00`

### or making well formed URIs with no url params in GET (not sure about this as well.)

> request header: GET `http://example.com/api/v1/serials/date_from/2013.01.01/date_to/2014.01.01/userid/112/is_in/0/starts_with/afx00`

Which one fits the best in the RESTful API architecture? Which should I use and why? Or maybe are there any other options for what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without question using URL parameters is best. It allows consumers to query for serials using their choice of filters. Your API should support returning results based on UserId alone, or a date range, or both. Or other combinations of inputs that make sense.

Embedding the key/value pairs of the filter in the resource path is an anti-pattern. It's difficult to understand what each path element means, and you would need to contort your routing engine to accommodate additional filter criteria. It also provides no flexibility in terms of choosing what filter criteria to use - you would in fact need to construct multiple resources paths for each combination of filters. And there is the management of ordering each pair (with URL params, ordering doesn't matter). Probably more reasons to avoid this, but those are the first that spring to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Bot GET methods can be used. It is your choise. But I'll prefer using url params. It is easier.

Comment: Thnak your answer that was the most likeable solution for me too.
And an other question: Can I use url params in a request with DELETE method or should I send form data with it?

Comment: No, you can use url params only with get request. In case of DELETE method you need FormParam